Equations for an embedded curve in projective space
Given $X$ a compact Riemann Surface, and an embedding into $\mathbb{P}^n$, how can the equations for the image be computed? My problem is that I really don't know how to work with non-complete intersections. When $X$ is indeed a complete intersection and $n$ is not too big one can just play around with the expression of the embedding to obtain the $n-1$ equations, but in general how does one obtain the "extra ones"?
Even if there may be not a general way to do it, are there any examples which can be useful to keep in mind?

I think this is a very hard question and also that there is no general method.

When you say "an embedding in to $\Bbb P^n$", how is that given to you? Like, what is the structure of that data?

@KReiser Right now I'm interested in the case in which it's obtained from a very ample divisor, so the embedding is a (n+1)-tuple of meromorphic functions on X.

And how is each meromorphic function given? As a collection of Laurent series, one for each open set in an open cover of $X$?

In general, yes. In a specific case that motivated me to ask this, they are obtained from the projections to the x and y axis of the "finite part" of an hyperelliptic curve (extended to meromorphic functions on the whole hyperelliptic curve).

This answer of mine over at MO may help, but I'm not sure if it's effective in practice.

Consider the three-uple embedding of ${\Bbb P}^1$. It lands as the twisted cubic curve. A parametrization is $(x:y:z:w)=(s^3:s^2t:st^2:t^3)$ and the image is not a complete intersection since three is not two times two. Two quadrics can meet in a degree four genus one curve or a twisted cubic and a line (three plus one). The way to get rid of the superfluous line is to find a third quadric that also contains the curve but a different line skew to the other line such that the three-way intersection is just the cubic. The quadrics for the above are $\langle xw-yz, xz-y^2,yw-z^2\rangle$. The first two also meet in $x=y=0$, the first and third also meet in $z=w=0,$ the second and third in $y=z=0.$

I'm sorry, what were you referring to by pointing out "three is not two times two"?

@user720386 Degrees for complete intersections are given by Bezout
